# How to install modules from PyDev Eclipse

Tags: python, pydev, cx-oracle

I need to install cx_Oracle module for python from pip. But due to the access restrictions in python installed folder, i am not able to install it.

Could someone can able to provide me the workaround for this issue or any way to install it from Pydev from eclipse ?

Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using the following command

pip install --target=d:\your\folder\default package_name

Then add that target file path to PYTHONPATH using system environment variable.